# while exporting datatable to excel the decimal values such as 5 then 5.1,5.2 in the columns creates a new whole line and makes the excel sheet messy

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datatable, export

My column has values like 2 then 2.1 then 2.2 but i want all that in one cell only but instead i am getting whole new line for the increase in series.
  I cannot use any 3rd party library as i am instructed not to so anyone know how to solve the issue with this code 
note : cannot use gridview nor any 3rd party tools and this is the only other code which worked fine.

```
        DataTable dt = ExcelDS.Tables[0];
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=AuditAnalysicReport.xls";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        string tab = "";
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
            tab = "\t";
        }
        Response.Write("\n");
        int i;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            tab = "";
            for (i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
                tab = "\t";
            }
            Response.Write("\n");
        }
        Response.End();
```

Answer (score 3):

convert the float value to string while returning from sql

```
CONVERT(nvarchar,ColumnName) as ColumnName
```

then it won't create new whole line

Comment: it is a whole sentence like a point
5.1 hi i am james bond 
5.1.2 i am an agent 

all in one column ....this whole is a string value

Comment: It''s working for me please check this images [link](https://snipboard.io/eEXuPA.jpg)

Comment: i tried but its coming same only it dint work for me